# Is there some way to get the result I show in the picture in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, arrow-functions

perhaps someone else has run across this issue and can provide some guidance on how to solve it using JavaScript.

Before somebody flag this question, please take a moment to read the problem and give some clue.
No code posted because I just need some guidance or example what I have done so far won't work.

The issue is as follows: (For a visual reference, see the photo)

If I have 51 clients, I need to distribute licenses in accordance with the applicable licensing schema in such a manner that the number of tenants increases by 10. For instance:

With 51 as the input number, there are 5 fixed schemas, and licenses must be applied as seen in Use Case 1's illustration.

First ten apply to the "1 to 10" scheme.
Schema "11 to 30" applies to Next 20.
Applying Next 20 to Schema "31 to 50"
and leftover 1 to the next schema "51 to 100".

The simple part is to loop up by 10, however I'm having trouble controlling the numbers to achieve a logic that works for all usage scenarios.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What are you having trouble with? You could use operators like division `/`, modulus `%` (gives remainder after division).

Comment: you mean, for example, subtracting the first 10, then dividing by 4, subtracting the next 10 dividings by 3, and so on... using the mod?

not clear about your approach but it sounds different from what I was doing :) I can give it a try.

Comment: Create a map/object from tenant number range (key) to license schema range (value). Then create a function `getLicenseSchema(tenantNumber)` which will iterate on that map/object (or directly get) and return the schema it belongs to. Since you didn't add any sample schema or examples, it is hard to provide more specific implementation details.

Comment: the schema is in last column "License Schema that appplies" and the prices for each schema is te license price

"1 to 10"---------->$80
"11 to  30"---------->$70  
"31 to 50"---------->$60  
"51 to 100 "---------->$50 
"101 - * "---------->$40

The key to getting the split from a given number:
Ex. 51 needs to split to 10,20,20,1
153 needs to split to 10,20,30,40,53

Comment: The schema isn't very clear to me from the description.  One sequence uses 10,20,20 while another uses 10,20,30,40.  What should the sequence be for 60 tenants then? Anyway, I agree with @Nikhil that a map/object (lookup table) would be the easiest way to implement it.